# How to change a curve in shiny in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to change the numbers in order to animate the plot. I have tried this

```html
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Equation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "values",
                  label = "number of values:",
                  min = -5,
                  max = 5,
                  value = 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    k <- function(x,c) { 
      p <- (-x^3+c)
      return(p)
    } 
    gg <- function(c_val) {
      ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-50, 50)), aes(x)) +
        stat_function(fun = k, args = list(c=c_val), aes(colour = "temp"))}
    gg(-5)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I can see the plot and the sidebar, but when I move the sidebar, it does not change. I struggled to change the plot. I understand it may not change significantly, but it does not matter for the purpose of these codes.

I wonder if we could do it using shiny.

Comment: Have you tried using `input$values` somewhere in your plot code? `ggplot2` is not going to spontaneously look for variables you haven't declared/assigned.

Comment: Also, when you use `input$values`, what you will get is not really an animation. If you want that, you will have to look into the `gganimate` package. However, you may have meant something different when you said animate.

Comment: Yes like this only (inside renderPlot), but the plot vanishes df <- data_frame(x = input$x %>% str_split(",", simplify = TRUE) %>% str_trim(). by animation, I just want to use different values to get different plot.

Comment: @user330 Sure I can but honestly you r plot does not really change no matter what value you put in `gg(c_val)`. There is only a "level" change, which means that the values become bigger or smaller but there is not real change in the plot itself. What's more, you see the level changes only when `c_val` is significanly bigger. E.g. Try `gg(5)` vs `gg(50000)`. You are not going to see these changes in your app because the slider is restricted to only -5 and 5.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS  I have updated, so you may wish to help if at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give an input to your ggplot: replace `gg(-5)` by `gg(input$values)`. And as said in the comment, as your slider just change the offset of the curve, you need proper scales to see the changes. I set it to -5:5:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Equation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "values",
                  label = "number of values:",
                  min = -5,
                  max = 5,
                  value = 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    k <- function(x,c) { 
      p <- (-x^3+c)
      return(p)
    } 
    gg <- function(c_val) {
      ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), aes(x)) +
        stat_function(fun = k, args = list(c=c_val), aes(colour = "temp"))}
    gg(input$values)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```